# RSpec Application Helper Test: Undefined local variable or method `helper`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This seemed to be a flickering sort of a bug for a while,but now it's appearing consistently: when I run RSpec on a fairly simple `ApplicationHelper` spec, I get the following error:

```
% rspec --backtrace
  1) ApplicationHelper renders Markdown from plain text                                                                                                                           
     Failure/Error: expect(helper.md(plaintext)).to eq("<h1 id=\"header\">Header</h1>\n")
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `helper' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationHelper_2:0x000001248d1218>
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-expectations-0f7b78587ab4/lib/rspec/matchers.rb:903:in `method_missing'
     # ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:148:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:148:in `block in run'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:208:in `call'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:208:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Procsy>'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-rails-480b173c9ad6/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:292:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:292:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:430:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:208:in `call'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:208:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Procsy>'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:432:in `run'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:485:in `run'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:301:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:145:in `run'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:494:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `map'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:457:in `run'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `map'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `block in run_specs'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:49:in `report'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
     # /Users/danielsh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@project-staging-ng/bundler/gems/rspec-core-4219c4786f6f/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /Users/danielsh/Dropbox/Project/Websites/Angular/bin/rspec:20:in `load'
     # /Users/danielsh/Dropbox/Project/Websites/Angular/bin/rspec:20:in `<main>'
```

Here's the complete spec file (`spec_helper` is included as part of my `.rspec` file):

```
describe ApplicationHelper do
  it 'renders Markdown from plain text' do
    plaintext = '# Header'
    expect(helper.md(plaintext)).to eq("<h1 id=\"header\">Header</h1>\n")
  end
end
```

This was working up until recently, but I'm not certain what I could have done to break such a basic feature. I'm using edge versions of Rails and RSpec, but didn't see anything in their git repos to suggest that `helper` had been deprecated---and running `rails g helper foo` still generates a `foo_helper_spec.rb` file with instructions indicating that `helper` contains the helper itself. If anyone has any ideas, I'd be grateful for them!

Comment: how are you defining `ApplicationHelper`?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward as well, at least as far as I can see. Here's a gist, since the comment won't take a code sample: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/752547b5c480391893aa

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created a new Rails project with a fresh RSpec installation, and it led me to the problem. Apparently one of the recent betas introduced a configuration directive called `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` that was missing from my slightly older `spec_helper` file; without it, RSpec wasn't guessing the spec type and mixing in the associated methods. Beware breaking changes!

Comment: @codenoob You have to add `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` in your `spec_helper.rb` file.

Thanks! @Daniel ! This helped me

Answer (score 8):

add `:type => :helper` 
so your code should look like

```
describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
 ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a weird error !! are you sure you required `spec_helper` in your spec ?

Anyway you could try without the `helper` method:

**First** you should first add to `/spec/spec_helper.rb` the following:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include ApplicationHelper
end
```

**Then** test without `helper` , so it will be:

```
describe ApplicationHelper do
  it 'renders Markdown from plain text' do
    plaintext = '# Header'
    expect(md(plaintext)).to eq("<h1 id=\"header\">Header</h1>\n")
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi there! Including `ApplicationHelper` and testing without `helper` turned the suite green again, but I'm not sure what that would indicate. I'm including `spec_helper` in `.rspec`, but adding it to the spec itself doesn't change things any.

Answer (score 0):

From the backtrace, it doesn't look like you're using the `rspec-rails` gem - just `rspec-core` and `rspec-expectations`.

`rspec-rails` is what provides the `helper` method to your helper specs. From inside a spec in my codebase:

```
(rdb:1) self.method(:helper).source_location
["/home/becky/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/helper_example_group.rb", 19]
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issues and when I run that command while debugging the test I get :

    ["/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb", 110]

I do have the rspec-rails gem included